# Do my Schoenfeld test and plot contradict each other?

Tags: r, cox-model, schoenfeld-residuals

I have assembled a multivariable Cox proportional hazard model like this:

```
res.cox <-
  coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ 
          AGE +
          B + 
          C, 
        data = data)
```

When I use `cox.zph(res.cox)` I get a violation for proportional hazard assumptions for the first two variables (and a global violation):

```
                                 chisq df       p
AGE                           1.41e+01  1 0.00017
B                             2.10e+02  1 < 2e-16
C                             2.99e-03  1 0.95638
GLOBAL                        2.15e+02  3 < 2e-16
```

But when I draw graphs of the scaled Schoenfeld residuals against the transformed time using `ggcoxzph(cox.zph(res.cox))[1]`, the CI overlaps 0 all the way (first variable for impression, its the same for the others):
[image]

It seems to me that this contradicts every issue and article I found:

- [How to interpret the schoenfeld residuals plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/580104/how-to-interpret-the-schoenfeld-residuals-plot)
- [Schoenfeld residuals - Plain English explanation, please!](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/547078/schoenfeld-residuals-plain-english-explanation-please)
- http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/cox-model-assumptions

**What am I doing wrong?**

BTW, this is the summary for `res.cox`:

```
  n= 2521, number of events= 2424 

                                   coef exp(coef)  se(coef)       z Pr(>|z|)    
AGE                            0.005123  1.005136  0.001574   3.254  0.00114 ** 
B                              -0.677403  0.507935  0.039421 -17.184  < 2e-16 ***
B                              -0.122768  0.884469  0.051108  -2.402  0.01630 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

                              exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
AGE                              1.0051     0.9949    1.0020    1.0082
B                                0.5079     1.9688    0.4702    0.5487
C                                0.8845     1.1306    0.8002    0.9777

Concordance= 0.648  (se = 0.007 )
Likelihood ratio test= 443.2  on 3 df,   p=<2e-16
Wald test            = 315.5  on 3 df,   p=<2e-16
Score (logrank) test = 304.6  on 3 df,   p=<2e-16
```

### UPDATED 14/2/2023:

As @EdM kindly mentioned, the problem was a bug in the 'survminer' package. Luckily, the repo [has now been updated](https://github.com/kassambara/survminer/commit/64de6746a7ee9cd758dc8d14ca88c8383e6851a6), and the [PR](https://github.com/kassambara/survminer/pull/535) with the solution was merged.

#### Example

`plot(cox.zph(res.cox), var='AGE')` shows:
[image]
and `ggcoxzph(cox.zph(res.cox))[1]` shows:
[image]

**The CRAN package has yet to be updated, you can install the latest version from GitHub as mentioned in the repo:**

```
if(!require(devtools)) install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("kassambara/survminer", build_vignettes = FALSE)
library("survminer")
```

Comment: Glad to see this is finally being addressed. You will still need to expand the y-axis of your plots to evaluate the smoothed curve and its errors, though. Now that you have seen the wide range of individual residuals, they will only distract you from trying to gauge the magnitude of the overall deviation from proportional hazards. Omit the individual residuals from the plot; focus on the smoothed curve with its (now correct) estimated error. You might also consider a different transformation of the time axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing you are doing wrong is using a [software package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=survminer) that might still have a long-standing coding error. That error makes its Schoenfeld residual plots essentially useless. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/560975/28500) for an explanation and a way to mend the code, if you want to stay with that package. I generally stick with the standard plotting provided by the [`survival` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=survival).

The other issue is your very large data set with over 2000 events. With that many events you can easily have "statistically significant" violations of proportional hazards that are of little practical significance. The "practical significance" is a judgment call that will be easier to make once you have a useful plot.

Also, an improperly modeled continuous predictor can show proportional hazards violations that are fixed when the predictor is modeled appropriately (e.g., with a regression spline). That could be what's going on with `AGE`, and with `B` if `B` is continuous.

Comment: Excellent catch and very lovely pointers. Thank you very much! Apparently, there is a [long-standing PR](https://github.com/kassambara/survminer/pull/535) for this. I have a follow-up question about the "practical significance" I guess this deserves another question, right?

Comment: @arielhasidim This site prefers to have one main question per page, so please do ask another. Look at [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/422539/28500) and its links for some thoughts on proportional hazards and "practical significance," to help focus your next question.