# Cox model: extremely high Schoenfeld residuals

Tags: survival, cox-model, proportional-hazards, schoenfeld-residuals

I have run fixed in time Cox models (crude and covariate adjusted) for the effect of a binary exposure. Sample size is approx. 200,000 and there are approx. 10,000 events and 4000 "yes" values for the exposure.

I am concerned and confused by the very large values of the scaled Schoenfeld residuals, please see plot below from the crude model. The very high (50+ in magnitude) values appear to be from both exposed (5) and non-exposed (50) subjects.

[image]

I fitted the model using the coxph() function from the survival package in R. I used the cox.zph() function with identity transform from the same package to produce the plot shown.

**UPDATES**

```
library(survival)
library(tidyverse)
    
# fit model
 f1 <- coxph(formula = Surv(tstart, time, event) ~ exposed_bin,
    data = test_df,
    robust = TRUE,
    cluster = id1,
    x = TRUE)
        
# check ph
 ph_check <- cox.zph(f1)
        
# show some values of the Schoenfeld resids
 test_df %>% filter(event == 1) %>% arrange(time) %>% 
 select(id1, id2, exposed_bin, time, event) %>%
 bind_cols(scho_resid = ph_check$y) %>% 
 slice(176:200) %>% 
 print(n = 25)
```

[image]

[image]

plot of ph_check with KM transform and no residuals displayed...

[image]

Comment: Did you test for violation of the proportional hazard assumption using Schoenfeld residuals first?

Comment: @wjktrs, yes, I did so. I have updated my question to show this. The test suggests no significant violation of proportional hazards

Comment: I suspect that the large number of tied event times is leading to differences in the row order between your tibble (set via `arrange(time)`) and the order of Schoenfeld residuals provided by `cox.zph()` that you bound to the tibble. The high-magnitude residuals should all be for the very-low-prevalence `yes` exposures. You show exactly 1 `yes` exposure and 1 high-magnitude residual for each of times 67, 68, and 69, but they don't line up as they should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am concerned and confused by the very large values of the **scaled** Schoenfeld residuals...(emphasis added)

The scaling of Schoenfeld residuals is proportional to the number of events in the dataset. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/492941/28500), for example, or this snippet of code from the  `residuals.coxph()` function for the case of **scaled** Schoenfeld residuals:

```
if (otype == "scaledsch") {
            ndead <- sum(deaths)
            coef <- ifelse(is.na(object$coefficients), 0, object$coefficients)
            if (nvar == 1) 
                rr <- rr * vv * ndead + coef
            else {
                cname <- colnames(rr)
                rr <- drop(rr %*% vv * ndead + rep(coef, each = nrow(rr)))
                colnames(rr) <- cname
            }
        }
```

Here, the initial value of `rr` is the set of unscaled Schoenfeld residuals, and `vv` is the (non-robust) variance-covariance matrix of the coefficient estimates.

With a large number of deaths, as you have, the absolute values of scaled Schoenfeld residuals can be quite large. What's important is the overall shape of the smoothed plot over time.

Comment: Thank you for your help @EdM! I have added a few updates. I am still a bit unclear why there seems to be a massive jump in magnitude of the residuals with no clear pattern (please see far right column in my updates to the question). I am not quite sure if I did this correct, but I tried to align the values of the Schoenfeld residuals from the cox.zph object to my data, after filtering for just the events (=1) and then arranging by event times. I'm not sure if the cox.zph is still valid with a cluster robust option which I have used?

Comment: @user167591 `cox.zph()` extracts the non-robust covariance matrix from the model even if you specify a robust model. So it's valid with robust models. As my new comment on the question indicates, I think there's a discrepancy between how you are ordering cases within a single time value and how `cox.zph()` is ordering the same cases. Within each time value, I suspect that you will find the number of high-magnitude residuals to be the same as the number of `yes` exposure values for the time value.